# insertAdjacentHTML and Array variables

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Trying to replace using .innerHTML with .insertAdjacentHTML and running into an issue. It seems innerHTML will parse variables when replacing but insertAdjacentHTML will not. Any guidance would be appreciated.  Here is an example:

JS:

```
    var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'];

    function docW() {
        document.write(colors[3]);
    }

    function innerH() {
        var i = document.getElementById("here");
        i.innerHTML = (colors[3]);
    }

    function insertA() {
        var j = document.getElementById("here");
        j.insertAdjacentHTML = ('beforeEnd', colors[3].toString()); 
                                            //colors[3] doesn't work either
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <p>My favorite color is: <span id="here"> </span></p>

 <input id="write" type="button" value="Write" onclick="docW()" />
 <input id="inner" type="button" value="InnerHTML" onclick="innerH()" />
 <input id="adjacent" type="button" value="AdjacentHTML" onclick="insertA()" />
```

The first two work as expected, I can't get the third one to load anything or throw any errors.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.insertAdjacentHTML` is a function. You have to call it as a function - so in your case:

```
function insertA() {
    var j = document.getElementById("here");
    j.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', colors[3]);
}
```

What you were doing in your original code snippet was overriding the element `j`s `insertAdjacentHTML` method with `colors[3]` rather than appending to the element

Comment: Wow, too much Turkey yesterday. I should have seen that myself! Thank you for the assistance!